# React Native : How to position a Modal relative to its parent element inside the Flatlist component

Tags: react-native

I have a basic modal that I want to render at the position of the rendered item of the Flatlist component when pressed:

```
<FlatList style={{ height: "100%" }} data={allNotes} numColumns={1} renderItem= {renderNote}></FlatList>
```

```
const renderNote = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.itemStyle}
      onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
    >
      <Modal
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.relativeView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.itemText}>
        {item.text}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

When I set the absolute position on the modal or the child element of the modal, the modal always shows at the top of the screen and not relative to the parent element.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 relativeView: {
    position: "absolute",
    marginLeft: 20,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other UI elements like View, Text, or Image. Modal does not use the same components parent tree as other components, that's why they render on top of other views.

Modal is ported to its own host tree through [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).

For this purpose, recreating a modal for each element rendered in the list is not recommended.